# Center TextView vertically in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to center a TextView vertically in a RelativeLayout. The preview of Android Studio displays the layout how I want it:

[image: Preview of Android Studio]

But my phone shows this (I use a custom font):

[image: What I get on Android]

Why is the TextView not centered on my device?

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/favourites_item_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="#63FF87" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/color"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/color"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1."
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="#63FF87"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add android:layout_below="@+id/num in your textview with id hex

Comment: "hex" is under "num" now, but still not centered

Comment: The question title seems to be a bit inaccurate orientation-wise.

Comment: Do you want it to be in the center vertically of the parent layout or below the @+id/num textview?

Comment: Why do you have a RelativeLayout inside another one? Just use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in your TextViews.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to center something inside a RelativeLayout, apply this attribute to the child of that RelativeLayout.

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 0):

I removed one RelativeLayout and rearranged the elements a bit and now it's working (thanks to a comment by "Der Golem"). The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="@drawable/favourites_item_bg"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="#63FF87" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/color"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/color"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/color"
        android:text="1."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/color"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/color"
        android:text="#63FF87"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @DerGolem If you mean the one with the background color, this one is required. It's a color preview for a favourites menu.